# Getting 3 errors while working with Python

Tags: python, numpy

Here's my code:

```py
import numpy as np

def create_board():
    board = np.zeros((6, 7))
    return board

board = create_board()
game_over = False

while not game_over:
    # Ask for player 1 input
    # 3 errors: Expected indented block, expected expression, and statements must be seperated by newlines or semicolons
```

Why am I getting these errors? Is it because of the "while not game_over" loop? I put an indented block too! It's too hard to figure out!

Comment: We can't answer this without the code that actually raise those errors.

Comment: Right now your code produces an error because you open a loop without anything in it. you open an empty block, which is wrong.

Comment: Your indented block needs to contain actual code, not just comments. If you have nothing else to put there, put `pass` or `...` (though then what's the point of the block?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python expects an (indented) statement after a `while`. You only have comments (denoted with `#`) there, which are removed when Python runs the program. As a result, Python interprets this program to not have an indented statement after the `while`.

One solution is to add `pass`, which does nothing in Python, but satisfies the condition that there is some statement after a `while ...:`. You can replace this `pass` with the actual program once you get around to writing it. This `pass` is essentially a temporary measure to keep Python from complaining.

```
import numpy as np

def create_board():
    board = np.zeros((6, 7))
    return board

board = create_board()
game_over = False

while not game_over:
    # Ask for player 1 input
    # 3 errors: Expected indented block, expected expression, and statements must be seperated by newlines or semicolons
    pass
```

That is the only error I can see. Please update your question to include the errors you are experiencing if you want people to be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this exact solution out before you even answered! Thank you again!